# MVC 3 - Actionlink - Show/Hide Register if logged in/logged out

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.actionlink

How do I:
1. Move the register link "@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register")" to the home page
and
2. Show and Hide it based on if a user is logged in or logged out

I saw this tutorial awhile back but I can't find it again

-Jonny

Comment: Ok so I figured out the correct way to do it and here it is:

Comment: 1. Open and edit the _LogOnPartial.cshtml                          2. Place this code within the else condition and in front of this code "@:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn, "Account")]" - <div>Please @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account") or</div>                                                            It's done easily and correctly.

Comment: visual studio sample application has got this solution.

Answer (score 8):

**1: Move the register link "@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register")" to the home page**

Ans: no tutorials link given so i cant answer this

**2: Show and Hide it based on if a user is logged in or logged out**

inside razaor view do this

```
  @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
  {
     //whatver
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Prasad but I figured out a more correct way. - 1. Open and edit the _LogOnPartial.cshtml                          2. Place this code within the else condition and in front of this code "@:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn, "Account")]" - <div>Please @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account") or</div>    It's done easily and correctly.